# A possible obstruction for existence of limit cycle for analytic vector field on $S^2$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, limit-cycles

Is there an analytic vector field  $X$,on $S^2$  which possess  a limit cycle   but $X  $,  satisfy   $\nabla_X X =0$   or satisfy   $\nabla_X    JX=   0$    where    $J$    is the standard     almost complex structure of $S^2$    and $\nabla$      is the $LC$,connection associated to the standard metric of the      sphere ?

Comment: Because $J$ is covariant constant, i.e., $\nabla J = 0$, one has $\nabla_XJX=J(\nabla_X)$, so the two conditions are the same; they both say that the integral curves of $X$ are geodesics.  The only global solution on $S^2$ is $X\equiv0$.

Comment: @RobertBryant  Thank you for your comment.